# Why is my UIAnimate call animating instantaneously?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uianimation

I have a UILabel that I show at the top of a view while it is loading. Essentially, on `ViewDidAppear`, I call `ShowLoadingMessage(true)`, then fire my async network calls. When the calls are completed and successful, I call `ShowLoadingMessage(false)`.

The end result is that the label goes from 0 to 40, and regardless as to when the async call completes (nearly instantaneously or many seconds later), the bar just instantly disappears.

The expected behaviour I want is for it to call into this function, slide open the `LoadingMessageBar` `UILabel` by expanding the height to 40, then shrink height back to 0 *after the call is completed*. **I am not using the Y value because the message bar is a window object and will appear above the navigation bar.**

```
private void ShowLoadingMessage(bool isLoading)
{
    UIView.Animate(0.2f, () =>
    {
        if (isLoading) this.LoadingMessageBar.SetHeight(35);
        else this.LoadingMessageBar.SetHeight(0);
    });
}

// Shorthand method for updating the height of the frame of a UIView
public static float SetHeight(this UIView view, float height)
{
    view.Frame = new RectangleF(view.Frame.X, view.Frame.Y, view.Frame.Width, height);

    return view.Frame.Height;
}
```

I've tried using a lock to no avail. I've tried using the Y value of the Frame and then setting the Hidden property on completion. I can't seem to get it to avoid the instantaneous second call.

Any thoughts as to why it isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: Are you on the main thread when executing `ShowLoadingMessage`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Hmm, it must not be because I'm attempting to execute an async call and have the animation complete when the async call returns. Is that what's causing the issue? Any way to make that work?

Comment: Use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` for your `ShowLoadingMessage` call.